# Amazon S3 upload via JS: safe credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a video file to AWS S3 bucket without the user logging via google or anything (the user shouldn't have to do anything!) [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html) suggests that there are 3 options:

1. Using Amazon Cognito to authenticate users
2. Using web identity federation to authenticate users
3. Hard-coded in your application

3rd option works for me, but is not acceptable on production environment. 
1st and 2nd option both require a lot of hassling not just for developers but for a user also if I understood correctly.

```
// Not safe, but working!
/*AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: "myaccesskey",
      secretAccessKey: "mysecretkey",
      "region": "eu-central-1"   
 });*/

 AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';

 var s3 = new AWS.S3();

     var params = {
         Bucket: 'mybucketname',
         Key: file.name,
         Body: file
     };
     s3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
             console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
          } else {
             console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
          }
     });
```

I also tried loading credentials from json file but this also did not work.

> AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

The error with this approach is:

> aws-sdk-2.4.13.min.js?ver=0.0.1:5 Uncaught TypeError:
>   n.FileSystemCredentials is not a constructor

Will I need to use server scripts to upload the file? (create a proxy between my JS and S3)

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: someone suggested I followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html to make a safe requests via browser/js. Anyone tried it yet perhaps? Any JS examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer (if it can be called so) as I noticed this was not answered: I actually used server side AWS libraries to make this work and the variables were safely stored as ENV variables. Also, I changed some functionality so I did not need to use JS to make this work.

So did not need to fiddle with 1st and 2nd option mentioned above. 
If someone finds a JS solution for the above two methods I'll gladly accept their answer.